# Bash script variables not expanding as expected for ghost script command

Tags: bash

I want to combine two pdf's *content.pdf* and *another.pdf* into a single *output.pdf* file. If I do:

```
FILES=("content.pdf" "another.pdf")
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="output.pdf" -dAutoRotatePages=/None $(printf "'%s' " "${FILES[@]}")
```

I'll get an error:

> Error: /undefinedfilename in ('content.pdf')

But if I echo the same command instead:

```
echo "gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="output.pdf" -dAutoRotatePages=/None $(printf "'%s' " "${FILES[@]}")"
```

And copy-paste the output directly to terminal:

> gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None 'content.pdf' 'another.pdf'

The command works. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why is [google-sheets] tagged?

Comment: `echo` is useless for deciding if two commands are equivalent. After all, `echo "hello world" "goodbye world"` has the same output as `echo "hello world goodbye world"` or `echo hello world goodbye world`, even though the quotes make a huge difference between, say, `ls -l "file one" "file two"` and `ls -l "file one file two"`.

Comment: ...the important thing is to understand that _syntactic_ quotes are the ones that decide how world splitting will happen, whereas _literal_ quotes are the ones that are part of your data. `echo` prints literal quotes and ignores syntactic quotes, but it's only the syntactic quotes that do anything useful for parsing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename arguments are passed to the `gs` command surrounded with single quotes. That is, the command sees them as literal `'` characters (as part of the filename). You should delete `'`s around the `%s` in `printf`'s format string or you shouldn't use `printf` and command substitution at all. Simply

```
gs …options… "${FILES[@]}"
```

should work. Note that deleting `'`s around the `%s` won't work properly when filenames contain whitespace characters (or glob characters which may match existing filenames).

Comment: "shouldn't use `printf` and command substitution at all" is very much better; if your filenames contain spaces, it's going to behave badly.

Comment: That solved my problem. I though I had tried this already but it seems I did something stupid elsewhere. This works fine even with spaces in file names.